# Android In App Billing adding Google Wallet not working

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-pay

We want to enable In App billing in our app.  In our app's settings, we have two options:
[image]

However, when we click Set-up a merchant account, it just goes back to the home page without an error message. (We already have a Google Checkout account). Has anyone experienced this and what is the remedy?

Comment: Is your Google Checkout account a Merchant account already? I have a different problem where after I click "Set-up merchant account" and fill in the details and click Submit, nothing happens... not even a single error message... Maybe their v2 UI is broken in some way, try the v1 API for the Google Developer Console.